# Including nonfree modules in OpenCV 3.0.0

Tags: c++, opencv

```
#include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Ptr<SURF> surf = SURF::create();

    return 0;
}
```

The following code gives an error:

```
/home/shivam/1.cpp:2:45: fatal error: opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp>
```

But the header file is included in include\opencv2\features2d\features2d.hpp.
Have a look at this screenshot:
[image: location of features2d.hpp]
Here is my cmake file for 1.cpp

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( 1 )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( 1 1.cpp )
target_link_libraries( 1 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Comment: Have you recompiled opencv with contrib modules?

Comment: I recompiled but it gave the errors mentioned above.

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the code that produces the error?

Comment: I have posted the error. In code , i am using surf algorithm.

Comment: You probably forgot to use the namespace `cv::xfeatures2d`.

Comment: I have included using namespace cv. The folder named nonfree where featues2d file is located is not there in build.

Comment: look at the answer and check if it's clear. Next time post also the code, and you'll find the answer sooner.

Answer (score 4):

In OpenCV 3.0.0 `nonfree` module is in `xfeatures2d`, not `features2d`.

This code will compile:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2\xfeatures2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::xfeatures2d;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Ptr<SURF> surf = SURF::create();    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting the code late. I am having trouble even now. Here is my code http://ideone.com/guysS4

Comment: @shivammitra a lot of things don't compile with your code... But for sure you need to use the `Ptr<>` syntax I used above in OpenCV 3.0.0

Comment: See the edited post. I have posted your code and the above header file is there in the right place. Still, it gives same error.

Comment: @shivammitra that's not my code :D. The header is `xfeatures2d`, not `features2d`

Comment: xfeatures2d is not available in opencv2. features2d is available.

Comment: @shivammitra You're absolutely right. Then why you're asking a question about OpenCV 3.0.0?

Comment: I am really confused as hell. In my opencv 3.0.0 which I have downloaded only features2d is available in a folder called modules.

Comment: I have included my cmake file which I am using for building the program.

Comment: Yes, but in OpenCV 3.0 SURF is in contrib extra modules, inside `xfeatures2d`, which you should have installed.

Comment: One last question: Tell me what is <opencv_build_directory>,<opencv_contrib> and <opencv_source_directory> on readme https://github.com/itseez/opencv_contrib/

Comment: build_dir is where you build opencv, and wil contain all headers, libs etc... contrib is the one you downloaded from that site and that contains the source of contrib modules. source_dir is the standard opencv source code     (without contrib)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89488/discussion-between-shivam-mitra-and-miki).