# opencv 3.1.0 SurfFeatureDetector error

Tags: c++, opencv

İ am using this link of code [github main](https://github.com/doczhivago/rtObjectRecognition/blob/master/main.cpp)

```
SurfFeatureDetector detector(minH);
        detector.detect(object, kpObject);
```

But i am taking this error error: 'SurfFeatureDetector' was not declared in this scope

Comment: By the looks of it, you either missed a `using namespace cv;` or a header inclusion. Please explain what you have done so far, including whether you just copied the source from that link verbatim or passed some of the content by hand.

Comment: well i want to make and opencv surf and sift application like this "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ig6Uj-MZ_3c?autoplay=1"   can you help me please which ways will i have follow in opencv?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Including nonfree modules in OpenCV 3.0.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32542847/including-nonfree-modules-in-opencv-3-0-0)